# Why isn't this a counter-example $Var(X_1 + X_2) = \sigma^2 + \sigma^2$ for independent $X_i$ s.t. $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2$?

Tags: statistics, variance

#### 1 Hypothesis:

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent random variables on $\{-1, 1\}$ s.t.

$$
X_1(-1) = X_2(-1) = -1
$$

and

$$
X_1(1) = X_2(1) = 1.
$$

Furthermore, let each event on $\{-1, 1\}$ be equiprobable.

Then the mean of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is $0$, and the variance on each is

$$
\sigma^2 = (-1)^2 0.5 + (1)^2 0.5 = 1
$$

#### 2 Question:

Evidently, we have that $Var(X_1 + X_2) = \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 = 2$. But why isn't it in fact $4$ since

$$
(X_1 + X_2)(-1) = -1 + -1 = -2
$$

and

$$
(X_1 + X_2)(1) = 1 + 1 = 2
$$

so that

$$
Var(X_1 + X_2) = (-2)^2 \cdot 0.5 + (2)^2 \cdot 0.5 = 4?
$$

#### 3 Same question asked a different way

I agree that

$$
Var(kX)= k^2 \sigma^2
$$

So with that being the case, why don't we similarly have:

$$
Var(X_1 + X_2) = Var(2X_1) = Var(2X_2) = 2^2 \sigma^2 = 4 \sigma^2 = 4?
$$

Comment: You are omitting the cases in which $X_1+X_2=0$.  That happens half the time.

Comment: To be clear:  it is not the case that the probability that $X_1=1=X_2$ is $\frac 12$, as you have written.  As they are independent (by assumption) the joint probability is the product, hence $\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 14$.

Answer (score 0):

To be independent, you need $E(X_1X_2)=E(X_1)E(X_2)$.  But $X_1X_2=1$ because both rely on the underlying $\{-1,1\}$ in the same way.
To be independent, they each need their own choice of $-1$ or $1$.  Then you won't write $(X_1+X_2)(-1)$, but $X_1(-1)+X_2(-1)$ or $X_1(-1)+X_2(1)$ and so on.